# angularjs , ui-grid : Display information in a basic grid not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am a newbie in angularjs and ui-grid.
I am trying to display a basic grid with employee information- id, name, salary, designation, grade.

This is the output of running index.html : 
[image: This is the output of index.html. It is returning all the required data but one below the other (sometimes overlapping) and not in a grid format as expected.]
**app.js : **

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);
 
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'uiGridConstants', function ($scope, $http, uiGridConstants) {
  $scope.gridOptions1 = {
    enableSorting: true,
    columnDefs: [
      { field: 'eid' },
      { field: 'ename' },
      { field: 'salary' },
      { field: 'designation' },
      { field: 'grade', enableSorting: false }
    ],
    onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ) {
      $scope.grid1Api = gridApi;
    }
  };
  
scope.gridOptions2 = {
    enableSorting: true,
    onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ) {
      $scope.grid2Api = gridApi;
    },
    columnDefs: [
      {
        field: 'eid',
        sort: {
          direction: uiGridConstants.DESC,
          priority: 1
        }
      },
      {
          field: 'ename',
          sort: {
            direction: uiGridConstants.DESC,
            priority: 0
          }
        },
      {
          field: 'salary',
          sort: {
            direction: uiGridConstants.DESC,
            priority: 2
          }
       },
      { field: 'designation', enableSorting: false },
      {
          field: 'grade',
          sort: {
            direction: uiGridConstants.DESC,
            priority: 3
          }
      }
    ]
  };
 
   $http.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = "application/json";
 $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Basic dG9tY2F0OnRvbWNhdA==";  
 $http.get('http://localhost:8080/EmployeeManagementSystemAngJS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/viewEmployeesPath')
    .success(function(response) {
      $scope.gridOptions1.data = response;
      $scope.gridOptions2.data = response;
    });
}]);

**main.css : **
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}
**index.html : **
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js"></script>
<script
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="ui-grid-stable.js"></script>
<link href="ui-grid-stable.css"></link>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <br> <br>
  <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions1" class="grid"></div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="grid2" ui-grid="gridOptions2" class="grid"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Could any one point out where i am going wrong?

I could not find many references to ui-grid. A few links to good content will be very helpful.

I referred to [this](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/101_intro) and [this](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/102_sorting). Both result in the same output.
I have added ui-grid-stable.css and ui-grid-stable.js in the project folder itself.

Comment: Your snippet shows nothing. Where do you load main.css?

Comment: @mainguy
Hi. Thanks for the response.
Even if i load the main.css using
<link href="main.css"></link>
it makes no difference to the output.

Even if i do not load it, shouldn't the default height-width grid values come to use.

Apart from that, the code is just as is mentioned in the official ui-grid site, [ui-grid-site](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/101_intro).
Infact, even they haven't loaded the main.css file but the code seems to work fine for them.

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause but scope.gridOptions2 should be $scope.gridOptions2.

Comment: I tried that. It is wrong syntax. The browser throws an error.

Comment: You should provide a plunker or fiddle for that. Your link to <script src="ui-grid-stable.js"></script> does not have a valid path. Using scope instead of the injected $scope throws an error in my console. Your snippet is not working and your datasource fails to load because of cross-browser limitations. I really want to help you, but i'm stuck now.

Answer (score 1):

i meet the same problem
when i change the format of css to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/js/lib/ui-grid/ui-grid.min.css"/>
```

then it's fixed

Answer (score -2):

Try with this url, it worked for me :)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.css" type="text/css">
```